# Strange way of variable assignment

Tags: java, variable-assignment, bit, bitmask

I have been working in C++ and Java and in both the languages I have often times come across a strange way of variable assignment, using bitwise operators. Instead of what could have been a simple assignment using the assignment operator it is complicated using bit operators like left shift.
For example, in Java's ServerSocketChannel class we see the following assignments:

```
public static final int OP_READ = 1 << 0;
public static final int OP_WRITE = 1 << 2;
public static final int OP_CONNECT = 1 << 3;
public static final int OP_ACCEPT = 1 << 4;
```

I am trying to understand here what have we gained by using the << operator. We could  have made simple assignments to assign the variables as 1,4,8,16 respectively as below:

```
public static final int OP_READ = 1;
public static final int OP_WRITE = 4; 
public static final int OP_CONNECT = 8; 
public static final int OP_ACCEPT = 16;
```

What is the value add in using `<<` operator here ?

Comment: It makes it more clear that those are bitmasks, I believe.

Comment: Can you remember all the digits of `1073741824` in your head? Or would it not be easier to just write `1 << 30`?

Comment: *it is complicated using bit operators* actually the converse, `1<<4`  clearly states that fifth-bit is set.

Comment: Hmm.. if you think in terms of binary numbers yes, however as an application level java programmer, for me int a = 16 makes more sense than writing int a= 1<< 4.

Comment: Yes, but since you'll probably write something like `OP_READ | OP_WRITE` when using those constants it makes it clearer that those options are meant to be combined an that the binary output is what interests you.

Comment: OK, i get it now,  I can see it used in the manner you told. Thanks Federico

Answer (score 3):

This is for clarity/readability (when it matters).

At the byte code level, `OP_ACCEPT = 16` or `OP_ACCEPT = 1 << 4` are the same thing (via `javap -constants <YourClass>`)

It's just easier to see exactly how many times this has been shifted. Usually this matters when you do different operations that are bound to power of two operations.

On example would be `HashMap` (or I assume `HashXXX` structures), where, at least in java, buckets are chosen on the next power of two, always. This simplifies processing or may be, rationalizing, thus number of buckets is declared as :

```
 static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 1 << 4;
```

At the same time, where, power of two, does not matter, variables are not declared like this:

```
static final int TREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 8;
static final int MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY = 64
```

Think of how a bucket is chosen for example in case of `HashMap` via `(n - 1) & hash`, where `n` is the number of buckets (always a power of two). A default capacity of 16 (or better `1 << 4`), means that the last 4 bits are zero, doing a minus 1 will make them all ones. So, *in a way*, `1 << 4` for `HashMap` would mean that the last 4 bits *only* are taken into consideration (until next re-hash). Now think `1 << 28` for example... without shift this would be pretty long to reason about.

A least for me, for such cases, doing for example an `or` or `and` would make faster sense on such variables.

Answer (score -4):

They're the most efficient way of representing something whose state is defined by several "yes or no" properties. ACLs are a good example; if you have let's say 4 discrete permissions (read, write, execute, change policy), **it's better to store this in 1 byte rather than waste 4**.

When you left shift 1 bit, the number get multiplied by 2.

for example take binary number of 5 = 0101
after left shifting 1 time it will become 1010, that is equivalent to 10.

Comment: That's nice and all, but doesn't answer the question of using shifts vs directly writing the value.

Comment: We use this technique for bitwise manipulation of value. For example while building device driver of a printer.

Comment: That's still great and all, but you're still not answering the question about why `4` is not better than `1 << 2`.

Comment: Exactly, The purported answer tries to explain left shift operator. What I am asking is what is the benefit of using left shift in the example I have quoted above instead of making direct assignments to 1,4,8.16. The example I have quoted is from java's ServerSocketChannel class of nio package.

Comment: They're the most efficient way of representing something whose state is defined by several "yes or no" properties. ACLs are a good example; if you have let's say 4 discrete permissions (read, write, execute, change policy), it's better to store this in 1 byte rather than waste 4. These can be mapped to enumeration types in many languages for added convenience.

Comment: You're still not answering. @user496934 is not asking what bitmasks are or why they're useful. They're asking why you would write `1 << 2` instead of `4` when defining the mask.

Comment: Yes not answered. The example I have quoted is from core Java nio package. If you see each of the four variables are declared as int, so each of them will occupy 32 bits. So by using << operator we are not doing any space saving here

Comment: @user496934 you're saving space when combining them and having just one integer to store the combination instead of having one integer or boolean field for every option.

Comment: OK, but we could have still defined the variables as  int OP_READ = 1; instead of int OP_READ = 1 << 0 and still use OP_READ | OP_WRITE when we want to check if atleast one of them is set. But I see that using the << operator is clearer here. So am I right in assuming that using << in the context I have described is just for clarity?

Comment: @user496934 yes you would be right, as the result would be the same but programs are written for people to read and, incidentaly, for machines to execute :)